# Concatenate laravel blade variable in javascript string

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

hey guys am facing a problem here is my script

```
        function appendMessageToReceiver(data){
            let messageContent = '<div id="chatmessages" class="main-message-box st3"> <div class="message-dt st3"> <div class="message-inner-dt"> <p> ' + data.content + '</p> </div> <span> ' + data.created_at + ' </span> </div> <div class="messg-usr-img"> <img src="{{ asset('avatars/' . data.receiver_avatar ) }}" alt=""> </div> </div>';
            $messageWrapper.append(messageContent);
        }
```

how can i concatenate this
`{{ asset('avatars/' . data.receiver_avatar ) }}`
to get uniform html code calling image from asset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
function appendMessageToReceiver(data){
    let messageContent = '<div id="chatmessages" class="main-message-box st3"> <div class="message-dt st3"> <div class="message-inner-dt"> <p> '
        + data.content + '</p> </div> <span> '
        + data.created_at + ' </span> </div> <div class="messg-usr-img"> <img src="{{ asset('avatars') }}/' + data.receiver_avatar + '" alt=""> </div> </div>';
    $messageWrapper.append(messageContent);
}
```

Comment: i got the problem it was because php code is executed befor javascript so i could not compile javascript that was not yet interpreted buy the browser